# Client access vs broadcast data from web server

Tags: javascript, web, server

I'm looking for technique or skils to fix the ways for new web site.
This site show the read time data which located on server as file or data on memory.
I'll use Node.js for server-side. But I can't fix how to get the data and show that to web site user.
Because this data have to update per **1 second** at least.
I think it is similar to the stock price page.

I know there are a lot of ways to access data like AJAX, Angular.js, Socket.io.. 
Also each has pros and cons.

Which platform or framework is good in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ultimately depends on how much control you have over the server side. For data that needs to be refreshed every second, doing the polling on client side would place quite the load on the browser.

For instance, you could do it by simply using one of the many available frameworks to make http requests inside some form of interval. The downsides to this approach include:

- the interval needs to be run in the background all the time while the user is on the page
- the http request needs to be made for every interval to check if the data has changed
- comparison of data also needs to be performed by the browser, which can be quite heavy at 1 sec intervals

If you have some server control, it would be advisable to poll the data source *on the server*, i.e. using a proxying microservice, and use the server to perform change checking and only send data to clients *when it has changed*.

You could use Websockets to communicate those changes via a "push" style message instead of making the client browser do the heavy lifting. The flow would go something like:

- server starts polling when a new client starts listening on its socket
- server makes http requests for each polling interval, runs comparison for each result
- when result has changed, server broadcasts a socket message to all connected clients with new data

The main advantage to this is that all the client needs to do is "connect and listen". This even works with data sources you don't control – the server you provide can perform any data manipulation needed before it sends a message to the client, the source just needs to provide data when requested.

**EDIT**: just published a small library that accomplishes this goal: [Mighty Polling ⚡️ Socket Server](https://npmjs.com/package/mighty-polling-socket-server). Still young, examine for your use if using.